# reading strings in 2D arraay using %s qualifier

Tags: c

I need to read strings in the rows of a 2D array in C, use of %s qualifier and scanf is mandatory,code used is

```
int tc; 
scanf("%d",&tc); 
char ar[100][tc];
for(int i=0;i<tc;i++){
    printf("\n enter the string \n");
scanf("%s",ar[][i]);
printf("%s",ar[][i]);
}
```

I have tried using

```
scanf("%s",ar[100*i]);
```

but i am getting an error as "expected primary-expression before ']' token".... how to do it?

Comment: You need to provide 2 indices for your array as it is 2 dimensional. The line `scanf("%s", ar[][i]);` makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tooks like `tc` is test case count.

You need to have `char ar[tc][100];`

Then in loop, which runs till `tc` is exhausted, do stuffs :

```
scanf("%s",ar[i]); // Pass address of ith string
printf("%s",ar[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your scanf statement to :

```
scanf("%s",ar[i]);
```

and your printf statement to :

```
printf("%s",ar[i]);
```

A string is an array of characters.

In your declaration,

```
char ar[100][tc];
```

`100` is the number of strings, and `tc` is te number of characters in each strings.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I assume you want an array of `tc` strings, each string `100` characters long? That's not what you declare, you declare an array of `100` strings, each `tc` characters long.

From that is should be obvious that to get string `i` in the array, you need to use `ar[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf requires the the address of a string varible. So when you write

```
scanf("%s",ar[][i]);
```

it wrong.You should write

```
scanf("%s",ar[i]);
```

Secondly

```
printf("%s",ar[100*i]);
```

prints the 100*i th row which may not exist.
So use

```
printf("%s",ar[i]);
```

Moreover you shouldn't initialize a array at runtime so scanning tc may not work on some compilers. You need to fix the size of the array.

char ar[100][100];

Comment: VLA are allowed `C99`

Comment: Yes it is but unfortunately mine doesn't support variable length arrays so wouldn't it be better to allocate a bit of extra memory or rather using malloc for assignment.

Comment: You can't simply answer based on what your platform/environment support. _"you cannot initialize a array at runtime..."_ is misleading

Comment: But just because you are using a 25 years old version of the standard, you can't assume that everyone else is too. Unless the question is specifically tagged C90, always assume latest version of the standard. This is explained in the [C tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info).